# Sencha CMD: how to set default build targets

Tags: extjs, settings, sencha-cmd, extjs6

I created an ExtJS app using Sencha CMD. If I do

`sencha app build`

by default it builds to production, with both classic and modern.

I would build to development and modern only by default. Where can I set the default build parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dev mode: 
sencha app build development

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/extjs/cmd_app.html

to build the modern toolkit only, go into your app.json and look for the toolkit section, specify modern there